# Python error message:

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to write this code but I keep getting this error message and I am not sure how to fix it.

Pmdl = (wexctoinhib*int(Pexc))-(winhibtomdl*int(Pinhib))

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks so much!
Here is the code:

```
from scipy import array, linspace
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import exp, tanh
from numpy import *

def Temp2(z, t, Ta, Te, wexc, yexc, winhib, yinhib, whd, yhd, wexctoinhib, 
winhibtomdl, whdtospn, yspn, Tt):

# Dependence of Meth Concentration 
#
#    dx
#    -- = -x/Ta
#    dt
#
#    dy
#    -- = x/Ta - y/Te
#    dt
# x = interperitoneal 
# y = blood
# Ta is the time constant of Meth in the absorbtion
# Te is the time constant of Meth in elimination
x = z[0] # Rabbits density
y = z[1] # Sheep density
T = z[2]
D = float(x=1)
yt = D*(Ta/Te-1)**-1 * (exp(-t/Ta) - exp(-t/Te))
act = int(tanh(z[0]))
Pexc = (1+act)*(wexc*yt*yexc)
print(Pexc)
Pinhib = (1+act)*[winhib*yt*yinhib]
print(Pinhib)
Phd = (1+act)*[whd*yt*yhd]
print(Phd)
Pmdl = (wexctoinhib*int(Pexc))-(winhibtomdl*int(Pinhib)) 
print(Pmdl)
Pspn = Pmdl + whdtospn*Phd+yspn
print(Pspn)
V = array([-x/Ta, x/Ta - y/Te, (Pspn-(T-T0))/Tt])
return V


def main():
# set up our initial conditions
IC0 = 1
BC0 = 0
T0 = 37

z0 = array([IC0, BC0, T0])

# Parameters
Ta = 8.25
Te = 57.5
wexc = 1.225
yexc = -0.357
winhib = 1.335
yinhib = 1.463
whd = 0.872
yhd = -3.69
wexctoinhib = 7.47
winhibtomdl = 6.38
whdtospn = 5.66
yspn = -3.35
Tt = 89.2

# choose the time's we'd like to know the approximate solution
t = linspace(0., 1., 60)

# and solve
xode= integrate.odeint(Temp2, z0, t, args=(Ta, Te,  wexc, yexc, winhib, yinhib, whd, yhd, wexctoinhib, winhibtomdl, whdtospn, yspn, Tt))
print (xode)

#    # now, plot the solution curves
#    figure(1)
#    plot(t, xode[:,0], 'b-', linewidth=2)
#    plot(t, xode[:,1], 'g-', linewidth=2)
#    #axis([0,240,30, 40])
#    xlabel('Time (min)')
#    ylabel('Concentration of Meth in Organism')
#    title('Concentration of Meth in the Male Rats vs. Time')
#    legend(['1 mg/kg', '3 mg/kg', '5 mg/kg', '10 mg/kg'], loc=2, framealpha=0.)
#    tight_layout()
#    savefig('Male Rats and Meth.png',transparent=True)
#    show()

main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Comment: just debug step by step. the type of "Pinhib" is list, you should know the type of your var, all of them.

Comment: Try `Pinhib = (1+act)*(winhib*yt*yinhib)` instead of `Pinhib = (1+act)*[winhib*yt*yinhib]`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`Pinhib = (1+act)*[winhib*yt*yinhib]`

you are using brackets instead of parentheses. For complex math equations/order of operations, just use nested parentheses, so the line would become:

`Pinhib = (1+act)*(winhib*yt*yinhib)`

`[]` indicates lists and what not, which is converting `Pinhib` to some other type (a list!).

This code:

```
x = 5
y = 1
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
temp = (1+2)*[x*y]
print(type(temp))
```

Yields this:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'list'>
```

If you are ever confused about what types you are messing around with, just use `type(yourVariable)` generously and you can weed out where something is being casted to another type.